# Wordpress Rest API: Return more than 100 results

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex, wordpress-rest-api

I'm currently building a Vue webapp to display all custom post types, which recently exceeded 100 results. The Wordpress REST API limits the amount of posts to 100, and I'm unable to figure out how to paginate the requests so obtain all the posts on initial load.

My current code is as follows:

```
getPosts: function(context) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (context.state.posts) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          axios
            .get(
              "https://localhost:81/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/cap?per_page=100"
            )
            .then(response => {
              this.posts = response.data;
              context.commit("storePosts", response.data);
              console.log("Cap retrieved from Vuex!");
              //console.log(this.posts);
              resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
              reject(error);
            });
        }
      });
    }
```

I have the following `computed` code to display the results:

```
computed: {
    caps() {
      const caps = new Map();

      if (this.$store.state.loading === false) {
        sortPosts(this.$store.state.posts).forEach(post => {
          const c = post.acf.address.country;
          const s = post.acf.address.state;

          if (!resorts.has(c)) resorts.set(c, new Map());

          const stateMap = resorts.get(c);
          if (!stateMap.has(s)) stateMap.set(s, []);

          stateMap.get(s).push(post);
        });
      }
      return caps;
    }
  }
```

How can I initiate loading **all posts** without user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Place this in API REST website to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rest_{your_CPT}_collection_params', function ( $params, WP_Post_Type 
$post_type ) {
    if ( '{your_CPT}' === $post_type->name && isset( $params['per_page'] ) ) {
        $params['per_page']['maximum'] = PHP_INT_MAX;
    }
    return $params;
}, 10, 2 );
```